# want to pass false but getting Nameerror exception

Tags: python

```
import requests
import json

Base_url="http://127.0.0.1:5000"

payload={
   "task": "add task",
   "completed": false
}

response = requests.post(Base_url+"/tasks",data=payload)

print(response)
```

Comment: Please add the exceptions seen and an actual description that is not the title of the post.

Answer (score 1):

`false` is not a keyword in python. `False`, however, is.

Comment: ya...but still it is not helping

Comment: Then please post the full exception.

Comment: E:\AquaSecurity\venv\Scripts\python.exe "E:/AquaSecurity/create task.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/AquaSecurity/create task.py", line 9, in <module>
    "completed": false
NameError: name 'false' is not defined

Comment: Thanks for posting the exception. However, it doesn't look like you've implemented my suggested solution (changing "false" to "False").

Comment: In that case, is it possible you are executing an older version of the script? Double check that the file you are editing is the same file you are running - ensure that the names and directories match.

Comment: i am running the same file

Comment: please help bro

Comment: THere is a disconnect between what you are posting and what you are doing.  As suggested, by the other responder,  the exception does not match your statement that you changed the code and ran the changed code.  Double check your work and try again.